# Where do I place the startup code in NetBeans Platform

Tags: java, netbeans, startup, rcp

Is there a good place to stick startup code for a NetBeans Platform app? What I've been doing as a work around is have each of my TopComponents instantiate my App class if it has not been instantiated already. Seems kind of tedious. I found this in an online tutorial but was wondering if someone knew of a better approach.

```
public class Installer extends ModuleInstall {
   @Override
   public void restored() {
      // By default, do nothing.
      // Put your startup code here.
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing some one-time initialization (or shutdown operation) for a complete module is indeed best done in the ModuleInstaller.

At least it works fine for me.

I use it mainly to make sure OpenOffice that might or might not be started due to a user action from within my module is shutdown cleanly.

Comment: Thanks, its just strange to me that a module coming up for the first time is calling restored which one might think it is coming back up. So would you know if i should override uninstalled() or closed() for de-initialization logic?

Comment: Yes there is a close(). See the JavaDocs: http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-openide-modules/org/openide/modules/ModuleInstall.html

Comment: I created my above Installer class and my restored() method is not being called. Wonder if you have any tips on what i'm doing wrong. I also tried placing it in the WindowManager's invokeWhenUIReady() method without any luck per this site: http://netbeans.dzone.com/news/hooking-netbeans-platform-life